# Highlighting regions of interest in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In vanilla plotting, it is possible to use a `polygon` call in the `panel.first` argument to `plot` to highlight a background region. Is it possible to do the same in `ggplot2`? Can it be done while preserving the gridlines?

eg:

```
# plot hp and wt for mtcars data, highlighting region where hp/wt ratio < 35
with(mtcars,plot(hp,wt,
     panel.first=polygon(c(0,0,max(wt)*35),c(0,max(wt),max(wt)),
     col="#d8161688",border=NA)))
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, that's possible with ggplot2. To preserve the visibility of grid lines you can use alpha transparency. Note that, in general, the order in which geoms and stats are applied matters.

```
tmp <- with(mtcars, data.frame(x=c(0, 0, max(wt)*35), y=c(0, max(wt), max(wt))))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, wt)) + 
  geom_polygon(data=tmp, aes(x, y), fill="#d8161688") + 
  geom_point()
```

[image: ggplot2 output]

Comment: rcs, this is pretty cool, but can you explain why this color is transparent? thanks!

Comment: because of the last 2 digits in the RGB-string (0=fully transparent, FF=opaque, see ?rgb); one could also use the `alpha` aesthetics in `geom_polygon`