# Can one use polygon() or equivalent in lattice and ggplot2 plots?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, polygon, lattice

Is it possible to annotate `lattice` (or `ggplot2`) figures with elements created with `polygon()` (or elements created with a similar function) from the `graphics` library?

I'm not too familiar with either library beyond examples of simple graphs posted on the web and printed in Deepayan Sarkar's book. Therefore, while I have code for what I've been doing in R with the `graphics` library, pointing me to relevant, equivalent functions and usage examples for `lattice` or `ggplot2` specifically would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `?panel.polygon` and `?geom_polygon` respectively (admittedly there are no examples in lattice doc, but the idea is the same as with base graphics polygons)

Comment: Great question. I've noticed over the years that the lattice methods are not well-known. Also strong work on tagging.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3610291/269476 might be of interest

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a series of methods that allow adding graphical objects to lattice plots. In the latticeExtra package there are `layer` and the "+" methods. In pkg:lattice itself, one can add to existing plots with `trellis.focus(...)` followed by panel calls such as `panel.polygon()`. I've used these in the past to annotate contourplot()s.

If you do the example on help(contourplot) and then follow that by :

```
trellis.focus("panel", 1, 1)
do.call("panel.polygon", list(x =c(5,15,15,5,5), y=c(60,60,90,90,60) ) )
trellis.unfocus()
```

... you should see a rectangle with vertices c(5,60),  c(15,60), c(15,90), c(5,90) has been placed in panel # 1 of the plot. Notice tha thte numbering is bsed on lower left as (1,1). I have generally not used the object-orientation to return a vlaue from that do.call(), but I suspect it would succeed.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Here is the `ggplot2` version of the first example in `?polygon()`

```
x <- c(1:9,8:1)
y <- c(1,2*(5:3),2,-1,17,9,8,2:9)

ggplot(NULL, aes(1:10, 1:10)) + geom_point() +
  geom_polygon(aes(x, y), fill = "orange", colour = "skyblue", alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]