# Area series overlay in R plot

Tags: r

I have a levelplot that is generated from a simple 3 column csv file. The X column is distance along a track, Y is the water depth and Z is the water temperature. Since the levelplot function doesn't know about actual bottom depth, it will interpolate values below the sea floor. I would like to overlay a filled area series to obscure these values and depict the sea floor. I have the ability to add the actual bottom depths along the track to my csv file or I can create a second data series. I'm not sure how to add the overlay though. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is my r script:

`d<-read.csv("D:/R_plots/temp_data.csv",header=F,col.names=c("X","Y","Z"))
library(latticeExtra)
col.l <- colorRampPalette(c('blue', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red'))
col.divs<-20
levelplot(Z ~ X * Y, d, cuts=50, contour=TRUE, xlab="Distance", ylab="Depth (m)", main="Temperature", col.regions=col.l, at=seq(from=0,to=6,length=col.divs), panel=panel.2dsmoother, args=list(span=0.5))`

This is an example of what I currently have:
[image]

And here is what I'm trying to produce:
[image]

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304538/can-one-use-polygon-or-equivalent-in-lattice-and-ggplot2-plots

Comment: Thanks @user20650, that pointed me in the right direction. I was able to use a trellis function to add an xyarea panel with the desired graphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to use a trellis function to add an xyarea panel. The bathymetry data is loaded from a separate file and overlays the levelplot.

Here is a code example:

```
data<-read.csv("D:/R_plots/temp_data.csv",
header=F,col.names=c("X","Y","Z"))
bathy<-read.csv("D:/R_plots/Bathy.csv",header=F,col.names=c("A","B"))
library(latticeExtra)
col.l <- colorRampPalette(c('blue', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 
'orange', 'red'))
col.divs<-20
levelplot(Z ~ X * Y, d, cuts=50, contour=TRUE, 
         xlab="Distance (m)", ylab="Depth (m)",
         main="Temperature", col.regions=col.l,
         at=seq(from=-3,to=10,length=col.divs),
         panel=panel.2dsmoother, args=list(span=0.2))
trellis.focus("panel",1,1)
do.call("panel.xyarea",
       list(x=c(unlist(bathy["A"])), y=c(unlist(bathy["B"])),
       col="gray34",groups = NULL,origin = NULL))
trellis.unfocus()
```

Here is an example output:

[image]