# Plot a Region in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I generated a Matrix with 100 random x-y-Coordinates in the [-1,1]^2 Interval:

```
n <- 100
datam <- matrix(c(rep(1,n), 2*runif(n)-1, 2*runif(n)-1), n) 
# leading 1 column needed for computation
# second column has x coordinates, third column has y coordinates
```

and classified them into 2 classes -1 and 1 by a given target function f (a vector).
I computed a hypothesis function g and now want to visualize how good it matches the
target function f.

```
f <- c(1.0, 0.5320523, 0.6918301)   # the given target function
ylist <- sign(datam %*% f)    # classify into -1 and 1

# perceptron algorithm to find g:
perceptron = function(datam, ylist) {
  w <- c(1,0,0)             # starting vector
  made.mistake = TRUE 
  while (made.mistake) {
  made.mistake=FALSE 
  for (i in 1:n) {
  if (ylist[i] != sign(t(w) %*% datam[i,])) {
    w <- w + ylist[i]*datam[i,]
    made.mistake=TRUE 
  }
 }
}
return(w=w)
}

g <- perceptron(datam, ylist)
```

I now want to compare f to g in plot.

I can do this quite easily in mathematica. Shown here is the data set with the target function f that separates the data in the +1 and -1 parts:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMRap.png]

This mathematica plot shows both f and g in comparison (different data set and f)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmklo.png]

This is the corresponding mathematica code

```
ContourPlot[g.{1, x1, x2} == 0, {x1, -1, 1}, {x2, -1, 1}]
```

How can I do something similar in R (ggplot would be nice)?

Comment: Yes it is possible. However your example is not reproducible so I cannot answer you with code.

Comment: sorry, I added code for a working example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlighting regions of interest in ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610291/highlighting-regions-of-interest-in-ggplot2)

Comment: @James I am not sure if this is a duplicate. It seems to me the OP asks a methods to get discrimination boundaries from the data, rather than how to produce a shadow over a plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is still not reproducible. Look at my code and you will see that f and g are identical. Also, it seems as you are extrapolating the lines (second part of your questions) for data points you don't have. Have you any evidence that the discrimination should be linear?

```
#Data generation
n <- 10000
datam <- matrix(c(rep(1,n), 2*runif(n)-1, 2*runif(n)-1), n) 
# leading 1 column needed for computation
# second column has x coordinates, third column has y coordinates
datam.df<-data.frame(datam)
datam.df$X1<-NULL
f <- c(1.0, 0.5320523, 0.6918301)   # the given target function
f.col <- ifelse(sign(datam %*% f)==1,"darkred", "darkblue")    
f.fun<-sign(datam %*% f)

# perceptron algorithm to find g:
perceptron = function(datam, ylist) {
  w <- c(1,0,0)             # starting vector
  made.mistake = TRUE 
  while (made.mistake) {
  made.mistake=FALSE 
  for (i in 1:n) {
  if (ylist[i] != sign(t(w) %*% datam[i,])) {
    w <- w + ylist[i]*datam[i,]
    made.mistake=TRUE 
  }
 }
}
return(w=w)
}


g <- perceptron(datam, f.fun)
g.fun<-sign(datam %*% g)
```

**Plotting the overall data**

```
plot(datam.df$X2, datam.df$X3, col=f.col, pch=".", cex=2)
```

[image]

I will produce separate plots for the g and f function since something is not working in your example and f and g are identical. Once you sort this out you can put all in one plot.You can also see and choose if you want shadowing or not. If you have no evidence that the classification are linear it's probably more wise to use `chull()` to mark *the data you have*.

**For the f function**

```
plot(datam.df$X2, datam.df$X3, col=f.col, pch=".", xlim=c(-1,-0.5), ylim=c(-1,-.5), cex=3, main="f function")
datam.df.f<-datam.df[f.fun==1,]
ch.f<-chull(datam.df.f$X2, datam.df.f$X3 )
ch.f <- rbind(x = datam.df.f[ch.f, ], datam.df.f[ch.f[1], ])
polygon(ch.f, lwd=3, col=rgb(0,0,180,alpha=50, maxColorValue=255))
```

[image]

**For the g function**

```
    g.col <- ifelse(sign(datam %*% g)==1,"darkred", "darkblue")    
    plot(datam.df$X2, datam.df$X3, col=g.col, pch=".", xlim=c(-1,-0.5), ylim=c(-1,-.5), cex=3, main="g function")
    datam.df.g<-datam.df[g.fun==1,]
    ch.g<-chull(datam.df.g$X2, datam.df.g$X3 )
    ch.g <- rbind(x = datam.df.g[ch.g, ], datam.df.g[ch.g[1], ])
    polygon(ch.g, col=rgb(0,0,180,alpha=50, maxColorValue=255), lty=3, lwd=3)
```

[image]

the ch.f and ch.g objects are the coordinates for the "bag" around your points. You can extract the points to describe your line.

```
ch.f
lm.f<-lm(c(ch.f$X3[ ch.f$X2> -0.99 & ch.f$X2< -0.65 & ch.f$X3<0 ])~c(ch.f$X2[ ch.f$X2>-0.99 & ch.f$X2< -0.65 & ch.f$X3<0]))
curve(lm.f$coefficients[1]+x*lm.f$coefficients[2], from=-1., to=-0.59, lwd=5, add=T)
lm.g<-lm(c(ch.g$X3[ ch.g$X2> -0.99 & ch.g$X2< -0.65 & ch.g$X3<0 ])~c(ch.g$X2[ ch.g$X2>-0.99 & ch.g$X2< -0.65 & ch.g$X3<0]))
curve(lm.g$coefficients[1]+x*lm.g$coefficients[2], from=-1., to=-0.59, lwd=5, add=T, lty=3)
```

And you get

[image]

Unfortunately because f and g functions are same in your example you cannot see the different lines in the above picture

Comment: thanks. You chose n = 10000, with that many training samples f and g should be identical indeed, at least in the plot. The training data is linear separable because I made it that way: First generate 100 data points, then chose a linear function to separate them. Third, classify them in two classes, above and below the linear function. With the perception algorithm I now want to generate the (now unknown) linear function based on the classified training set.

Comment: The graphics look nice but can I have the line more linear, more abline() like?

Comment: Sure. The ch.f and ch.g objects are coordinates of the "bag". Extract the needed points, model them and project them. See my updated answer

Answer (score 3):

Same thing using `ggplot`. This example follows your code exactly, then adds at the end:

```
# OP's code...
# ...

glist <- sign(datam %*% g)

library(reshape2)  # for melt(...)
library(plyr)      # for .(...)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(datam,f=ylist,g=glist) # df has columns: X1, X2, X3, f, g
gg <- melt(df,id.vars=c("X1","X2","X3"),variable.name="model")

ggp <- ggplot(gg, aes(x=X2, y=X3, color=factor(value)))
ggp <- ggp + geom_point()
ggp <- ggp + geom_abline(subset=.(model=="f"),intercept=-f[1]/f[3],slope=-f[2]/f[3])
ggp <- ggp + geom_abline(subset=.(model=="g"),intercept=-g[1]/g[3],slope=-g[2]/g[3])
ggp <- ggp + facet_wrap(~model)
ggp <- ggp + scale_color_discrete(name="Mistake")
ggp <- ggp + labs(title=paste0("Comparison of Target (f) and Hypothesis (g) [n=",n,"]"))
ggp <- ggp + theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold"))
ggp
```

Below are results for `n=200, 500, and 1000`. When `n=100, g=c(1,0,0)`. You can see that f and g converge for `n~500`.

In case you are new to `ggplot`: first we create a data frame (`df`) which has the coordinates (`X2 and X3`) and two columns for the classifications based on `f` and `g`. Then we use `melt(...)` to convert this to a new dataframe, `gg`, in "long" format. `gg` has columns `X1, X2, X3, model, and value`. The column, `gg$model` identifies the model (`f or g`). The corresponding classifications are in `gg$value`. Then the ggplot calls do the following:

1. Establish the default dataset, gg, the x and y coords, and the coloring [`ggplot(...)`]
2. Add the points layer [`geom_point(...)`]
3. Add lines separating the classifications [`geom_abline(...)`]
4. Tell ggplot to plot the two models in different "facets" [`facet_wrap(...)`]
5. Set the legend name.
6. Set the plot title.
7. Make the plot title bold.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `col` argument in `plot()` to indicate classification of the `f()` function. And you can use `polygon()` to shade the classification area of your `g()` function. If you give us a reproducible example we could answer with specific code. It would result in a figure similar to that of Mathematica you present.